# C# cannot generate a random string

Tags: c#, .net, string, random

I cannot work out why C# is doing this.

Here's my code;

```
private string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        string randomString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            randomString += chars.ToCharArray()[new Random().Next(chars.ToCharArray().Length)];
        }

        return randomString;
    }
```

First result:
"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"

Second result:
"ssssssssssssssssssss"

Third result:
"mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm"

Comment: Stop generating a new Random instance every loop iteration. Declare and initialize it once outside the loop. (The loop is going too quickly and you're always getting the same seed.)

Comment: Make one `Random` object as all your random objects has the same seed (time).

Answer (score 1):

When you generate a random number generator using `new Random()`, its seed will be based on the current time, so it will end up being the same thing for each iteration of the loop, since execution will be fast. Instead, you want a `var rng = new Random()` outside of the loop, and use `rng.Next` inside the loop.

Comment: This worked thanks. I thought it would just create a new instance of Random and generate  new integer. Weird...

Comment: It certainly does generate a new instance of `Random`, but they all have the same seed, thus generating the same numbers.